# How to tell if socket connection breaks in python

Tags: python

When using sockets, how can I get the client to handle a broken connection?  When I have the client in `recv()` and I exit the server side without sending anything, the client stays stuck in `recv()`. How can I make it end when the connection is broken?

Answer (score 0):

First off, try setting the socket to non-blocking mode(blocking mode is default):

```
mysock.setblocking(0)
```

Now if you read or write from the socket, and the connection was terminated on the other end, I believe it should throw a `socket.error` when no data is received.

**Example:**

```
try:
    data = mysock.recv(1024)

except socket.error:
    # quit or something
```

Check out this link to the docs on `socket.setblocking` and `socket.settimeout`
https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking

Comment: but when i close the program by clicking x on the window beore the program is done running or sending something, the other side continues to try and read

Comment: so setblocking to non blocking makes the timeout 0? what if i wanted the program to wait indefinitely on recv() or until the connection gets destroyed?

Comment: I would advise reading these docs https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#when-sockets-die